# Issue regarding symlink in perl

Tags: perl

I have the below code that I got with the help from here only:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $link = 'abc';
my $link1 = readlink '/home/test/abc_test/xyz';
my $x = symlink "/home/test/abc_test/$link1", "/home/test/test_scripts/$link";
print "$x\n";
```

The problem is it is creating the below result:

```
abc -> /home/test/abc_test/test1 (suppose xyz is pointing to the directory "test1")
```

The result I need is as below:

```
abc -> test1
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a link in the same directory as the target file? Your `abc -> test1` seems to indicate that, but your code is using different directories for each.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to synlimk is the path you want for the target of link. You are getting `/home/test/abc_test/test1` because you are passing `/home/test/abc_test/test1`. If you want `test1`, you need to pass `test1`.

---

If you want to copy the exact target, you can use the following:

```
my $src_link = "$ENV{HOME}/tmp/abc_test/xyz";
my $dst_link = "$ENV{HOME}/tmp/test_scripts/xyz";

defined( my $target = readlink($src_link) )
   or die("Can't read symlink \"$src_link\": $!\n");

symlink($target, $dst_link);
   or die("Can't create symlink \"$dst_link\": $!\n");
```

For example, if you start with

```
/home/test/abc_test/xyz -> test1       # Points to /home/test/abc_scripts/test1
```

Then the above will create

```
/home/test/test_scripts/xyz -> test1   # Points to /home/test/test_scripts/test1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting the path you want to remove, so change it to:

```
my $x = symlink $link1, "/home/test/test_scripts/$link";
```

instead of what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the response but It is creating a deadlink

Comment: Did it create the link you wanted, but the target of the link doesn't exist?

Comment: actually both the link and target directory are appearing in Red and can't open